# Plotting small multiples using for loop and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Unit    Group    Feature1    Feature2    Feature3    Feature4
1         1        blue         x           a           12
2         1        yellow       y           b           15
3         2        green        x           a           13
4         3        indigo       z           c           12
5         1        green        y           b           16
```

I'd like to create a grid of visualizations (small multiples) where each row is a group, and each column contains proportions of each feature (ie. the table function, table(dataset$feature1)). I have done the following, however, am having a hard time creating a grid of these visualizations while using a for loop. Currently, I get four different images each with four charts. Any ideas on how to turn this into essentially a 4x4 grid of barcharts rather than 4 separate images?

```
library(gridExtra)

input_max_groups <- 4

for (i in 1:input_max_groups) {

dataset_subset <- subset(dataset, group== i)

feature1_df <- as.data.frame(table(dataset_subset$feature1)/nrow(dataset_subset)*100)

feature1_plot <- feature1_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()

feature2_df <- as.data.frame(table(dataset_subset$feature2)/nrow(dataset_subset)*100)

feature2_plot <- feature2_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()

feature3_df <- as.data.frame(table(dataset_subset$feature3)/nrow(dataset_subset)*100)

feature3_plot <- feature3_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()

feature4_df <- as.data.frame(table(dataset_subset$feature4)/nrow(dataset_subset)*100)

feature4_plot <- feature4_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()

plot <- grid.arrange(feature1_plot, feature2_plot, feature3_plot, feature4_plot, nrow=4)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

You can accomplish small multiples by using `facet_wrap()` and you can plot percentages instead of counts by using `stat = 'count'` in `geom_bar()` and mapping the y-aesthetic to the special variable `..prop..` for proportion.  In your case, you'll need to specify the group to get the proper proportion, and use `scales = 'free_x'` in the facet wrap to get the x-axis for each facet to contain only the variables of interest.

Now your data is **wide** and ggplot likes **long** data so you need to pivot the feature columns into rows to make your data longer using `pivot_longer`

This way you can leave out your loops and `grid.arrange` and do it in a single ggplot call.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset_subset <- tribble(
  ~"Unit", ~"Group", ~"Feature1", ~"Feature2", ~"Feature3", ~"Feature4",
  1,         1,        "blue"   ,   "x",           "a",           "12",
  2,         1,        "yellow",    "y",           "b",           "15",
  3,         2,        "green"  ,   "x",           "a",           "13",
  4,         3,        "indigo",    "z",           "c",           "12",
  5,         1,        "green"  ,   "y",           "b",           "16")


dataset_subset %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("Feature")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = name), stat = "count", fill = "#f68060", alpha =.6, width = .4) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Jake! What I actually want is the different values for features in the x-axis instead of group number. For example table(feature1) would give blue, yellow, indigo, green - and counts (or %) based on how many of each color make up that subset of data. So the x-axis for that barchart would contain each of those colors with counts in the y-axis. This is then created for each group number. I've created subsets of each group since ultimately I want a 4x4 grid of barcharts where each row contains a different group and each column a different feature plotted. Let me know if that's clear!

Comment: @ava I've updated the answer to reflect the addiitional information from your comment.

Comment: I'd like to modify the line " pivot_longer(contains("Feature"))" to something like "pivot_longer(cols = c(1:16))." I'd like to repeat this for c(17:32), c(33,48) and so on for all my data fields (have a total of 281 data fields) so that I get sets of 16 charts per image. Is there any way to specify this within the loop without manually repeating the loop for the different column ranges? I also can't just do "pivot_longer(dataset)" because I get way too many small multiples on the single image so it becomes unreadable. Any suggestions on this?